# Wifi disabled, have to turn off and turn on

Tags: networking, wireless, xubuntu

Aye,
i recently moved to Xubuntu 15.04 and from time to time when I wake up laptop from suspend wifi cannot connect. It says networking disabled. I tried turnig on option "Enable networking" but that gives me nothing. I have to restart laptop (and It's also a problem as sometimes turning off or trying to restart just logs me off, i have to turn it off the hard way) and then it works.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Xubuntu, try to run

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Then restart the PC. Also, you can check for additional drivers on the driver Utility.

If the problem persist, look at

```
dmesg
```

And attach the output on a text file.

Also, you can see this entry: [WiFi Issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos?lq=1)

Comment: Can you explain what those lines does?
I like to know :)

Comment: Sure!, autoremove, uninstall all the residual packages left for some programs after updates or other software removal or installation.

autoclean, erases residual packages from disk, to free disk space.

dpkg --configure -a: Configure a package which has been unpacked but not yet  configured.   If  -a  or  --pending is given instead of package, all unpacked but unconfigured packages are  configured.

For more information, you can do : man <command>, for example, 

man dpkg

Comment: Why i have -1 reputation. Something wrong with my answer? :(

Comment: I upvoted. But i think my votes doesnt counts yet

Comment: The problem is still on. Here is link to txt output from dmesg
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B08bH1wkIXqGOElIUE53b0dSQXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please, post the result of `lsmod` ,  `ifconfig `  and  `iplink `  . You can also try the solution given here: [link] (http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/wireless-became-disabled-how-do-i-enable-858357/) at comment #7. Also, you can try the solution given above by Mark Henderson.

Comment: lsmod:
http://textuploader.com/ao6td

Comment: ifconfig:
http://textuploader.com/ao6tj

Comment: and iplink is unknown command on my system

Comment: I dont know if its relevant but i noticed that when I launch my laptop, I dont get DOS screen. Y'know, "Press F12 to run DOS setup" shit. It's going straight to the Xubuntu login screen

Comment: I cannot see the brcmutil or brcmsmac module on your lsmod file. Have you searched for drivers with your driver utility? .  Which hardware are you using? PC model, processor, ram, OS version and kernel version.  However, here is one solution for this problem, read ahead: [Wifi not working after sleep on Xubuntu 14.04](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218043)

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, seems a little harsh. Possibly an accidental click?

At any rate, have you tried this:

http://www.techytalk.info/ubuntu-fix-network-stopped-working-after-resume-from-sleep/

And if you are struggling to follow that solution, paste the results of "sudo lsmod" and we can go from there.